# Post-request rejected by server

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

Could anyone help to solve a problem? I'm trying to send data form from authorize user to protected controller method,   using fetch and getting  400 error. I'm using NET CORE 5 MVC  and on front-en  bootstrap 5. If I remove ValidateAntiForgeryToken from AddItemToStore method I'm getting 415 error

C# code

```
  [Authorize]
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult AddItemToStore([FromBody] StoreUser itemsStore)
{
    StoreUser str = new StoreUser
    {

        Id = 1,
        UserId = itemsStore.UserId,
        CatrgoryId = itemsStore.CatrgoryId
    };

    return Ok(str);
}
```

JS-code

```js
var buttonAddOrder = document.getElementById("addToOrder");

buttonAddOrder?.addEventListener("click", function () {
    var catId = document.querySelector("#formToStore input[name = 'cardId']").value;
    var userId = document.querySelector("#formToStore input[name = 'userId']").value;
    var antiForgeryToken = document.querySelector("#formToStore input[name = '__RequestVerificationToken']").value;
    var itemsStore = {
        __RequestVerificationToken: antiForgeryToken,
        UserId: userId,
        CatrgoryId: catId,
        Payed: false
    };
    var url = "/CategoriesToUser/AddItemToStore"; 
    

    var response = fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'cors',
        cache: 'no-cache',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8;'
        },
        body: {
           
            itemsStore: itemsStore
        }
    })
        .then((response) => {
            return response.json();
        }).catch((e) => console.log(e.message));
    console.log('buttonAddOrder', response);
```

HTML

```html
<form id="formToStore" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" name="cardId" id="cardId" /> @{ var getUser = await UserManager.GetUserAsync(User); }
  <input type="hidden" name="userId" asp-for="@getUser.Id" />

  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" id="buttonclose" name="buttonclose" class="buttonclose btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

    <button type="button" id="addToOrder" name="addToOrder" class="btn btn-primary">
                        Add to Order
                    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

An attempt of using FormData  doesn't work, the same error.

```js
buttonAddOrder?.addEventListener("click", function () {
  
    var url = "/CategoriesToUser/AddItemToStore";
    const  formToStore = document.getElementById('formToStore');
    var formOrder = new FormData(formToStore);
   
    let response = fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'cors',
        cache: 'no-cache',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8;'
        },
        body: formOrder
    })
        .then((response) => {
            return response.json();
        }).catch((e) => console.log(e.message));
    console.log('buttonAddOrder', response);
   
});
```

But If I send data to anonymous post method without using  ValidateAntiForgeryToken on beck-end It's work.
Example:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]   
public IActionResult AddItemToStore([FromBody] StoreUser itemsStore)
{
    StoreUser str = new StoreUser
    {

        Id = 1,
        UserId = itemsStore.UserId,
        CatrgoryId = itemsStore.CatrgoryId
    };

    return Ok(str);
}
```

Screenshots

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

Comment: Why is the RVT twice in the body?

Comment: It just for testing, I  tried different ways to include the RVT into request.  Because, I thought there's  something wrong with this token.

Comment: @ZergZerg Could you try removing `multipart/form-data`?

Comment: Also, I could not see `Html.AntiForgeryToken()` within your form tags. Make sure you put it inside the form tag and try

Comment: @Anindya Dey I removed multipart/form-data and it still doesn't work, the same error. AntiForgeryToken generate automatically  in form, on the first screen there is a token

Comment: @Anindya Dey I thought it's unnessesary to generate it explicitly by html-tag

Comment: No matter you set `multipart/form-data` or not does not influence the result because you use fetch api to post the data. Two ways you can follow in my shared answer below. Pls check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before coding, you need be sure the following inputs contain value:

```
<input type="hidden" name="cardId" id="cardId" /> @{ var getUser = await UserManager.GetUserAsync(User); }
<input type="hidden" name="userId" asp-for="@getUser.Id" />
```

Two ways you could follow:

### 1.From Body:

View

```
<form id="formToStore" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" name="cardId" id="cardId" value="1" /> 
  <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="466788cb-6aab-4798-81f1-f6b05cb71e32"/>

  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" id="buttonclose" name="buttonclose" class="buttonclose btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

    <button type="button" id="addToOrder" name="addToOrder" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Order</button>
  </div>
</form>
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        var buttonAddOrder = document.getElementById("addToOrder");    
        buttonAddOrder?.addEventListener("click", function () {
            var catId = document.querySelector("#formToStore input[name = 'cardId']").value;
            var userId = document.querySelector("#formToStore input[name = 'userId']").value;
            var antiForgeryToken = document.querySelector("#formToStore input[name = '__RequestVerificationToken']").value;
            var itemsStore = {
               // __RequestVerificationToken: antiForgeryToken,  //remove this....
               UserId:userId,
               CatrgoryId: catId,
               Payed: false
            };
            var url = "/CategoriesToUser/AddItemToStore";          
            var response = fetch(url, {
                method: 'POST',
                mode: 'cors',
                cache: 'no-cache',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',          //change here...
                    "X-ANTI-FORGERY-TOKEN": antiForgeryToken,    //add this.....    
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(itemsStore)          //change here.....                   
            })
            .then((response) => {
                return response.json();
            }).catch((e) => console.log(e.message));

        })
    </script>
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult AddItemToStore([FromBody] StoreUser itemsStore)
{
    //do your stuff....
    return Ok(itemsStore);
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
services.AddAntiforgery(x => x.HeaderName = "X-ANTI-FORGERY-TOKEN");
```

---

### 2.From Form:

View

```
<form id="formToStore" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                      @*change name="cardId" to name="CatrgoryId"*@
  <input type="hidden" name="CatrgoryId" id="cardId" value="1" />  
  <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="466788cb-6aab-4798-81f1-f6b05cb71e32"/>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" id="buttonclose" name="buttonclose" class="buttonclose btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" id="addToOrder" name="addToOrder" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Order</button>
  </div>
</form>
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        var buttonAddOrder = document.getElementById("addToOrder");
        buttonAddOrder?.addEventListener("click", function () {
        var url = "/CategoriesToUser/AddItemToStore";
        const  formToStore = document.getElementById('formToStore');
        var formOrder = new FormData(formToStore);

        let response = fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'cors',
            cache: 'no-cache',
            //headers: {
            //    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8;'
            //},                             //don't need to set the Content-Type header
            body: formOrder   
        })
            .then((response) => {
                return response.json();
            }).catch((e) => console.log(e.message));

        })
    </script>
}
```

Controller

Change `[FromBody]` to `[FromForm]`.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult AddItemToStore([FromForm] StoreUser itemsStore)
{
    //do your stuff...
    return Ok(itemsStore);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and detail response, it has worked. The post-data started receiving to the method. I used 1th way.